# iOS::When i click the UITextView or UITextField keyboard is not getiing properly

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, xcode6.1, ios8.1

When I click the `UITextView` , keyboard is getting like this image means below black screen
Anyone can you give me the suggesion for this.
Thanks in advance.

[image: When i am click the <code>UITextView</code> keyboard is like this image means below black screen]

Comment: is this in simulator or device?

Comment: Imposible to troubleshoot without a lot more information.

Comment: I am getting in simulator

Comment: Did you try resetting the simulator, exit and open again. If it didn't work. Please  post  your code.

Comment: yeah,It's working fine now,after reseted the smulator.Thanks and How can i give you points.

Comment: Glad it worked. You can give points by accepting the answer below with an upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's usually local issue(perhaps a bug), which might happen with prolonged usage without restart.

Resetting the simulator and restarting it would fix it.